.NET 9 Blazor WebAssembly, line by line debugging not working: "The debug adapter exited unexpectedly"
I have a .NET 9 Blazor WebAssembly app. I can add breakpoints to my C# code, and i can hit those breakpoints. However, as soon as i click F10 or F11 to execute the line, i am presented with this error, and the visual studio debugger crashes:

The error is:

The Debug adapter exited unexpectedly

I tried using Chrome and Edge.

I fixed the issue by clicking Tools => Options, and then enabling "Enable New .NET 9+ Mono Debugger"

